# Compare between $\ln(2)$, $\ln(-2)$

Tags: logarithms

$x^2 =(-x)^2, \;\forall x \in  \mathbb{R}^+$

$$\begin{align*}
\therefore \ln(x^2) &=\ln(-x)^2\\
2\ln(x)&=2\ln(-x)\\
\ln(x)&=\ln(-x)
\end{align*}$$

If the statement above is correct, then compare between: $\ln(2)$ and $\ln(-2)$?

My try is, I think the statement is wrong, because $x$ must be positive? any help?

Comment: By the way, named math operators should appear upright, and the common ones have their own code for this purpose (e.g. `\ln`, `\sin` - [see entry 11 in our MathJax guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264)).

Comment: $\ln(-x)^2$ is not clear in precedence.  It would be better to write $\ln((-x)^2)$ to distinguish from $(\ln(-x))^2$.  This does not change your argument.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the statement $2 \ln a = \ln (a^2)$ only works for $a > 0$.

For insight on why this is, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799200/what-did-johann-bernoulli-wrong-in-his-proof-of-ln-z-ln-z) explores that.

Comment: thank, but If you could delete you're answer, because I want to delete the question please