# Why don't we have $(\mathrm{cis}(2\pi))^{1/5} = (\mathrm{cis}(4\pi))^{1/5}$, while we do have $\mathrm{cis}(2\pi) = \mathrm{cis}(4\pi)$?

Tags: complex-numbers

If $\operatorname{cis}(2\pi) = \operatorname{cis}(4\pi)$, then don't we have $$\big(\operatorname{cis}(2\pi)\big)^{1/5} = \big(\operatorname{cis}(4\pi)\big)^{1/5}?$$

This isn't yielding the same answer, even though I'm raising two equal complex numbers to the power $1/5$ (or for that matter any number?).

Comment: $z^w$ is not single-valued unless $w$ is an integer.

Comment: The five fifth-roots lie at the vertices of a regular pentagon.  As you successively raise cis $ \frac{2 \pi}{5} \ $ or cis $ \frac{4 \pi}{5} \ $ to higher (integer) powers, on the left-hand side of your "equation", you encounter each root one after another, while on the right-hand side, you skip every other root.  So in this "cycling", you only "meet up" at $ \ z \ = \ 1 \ $ again after raising each of these roots to the fifth power.  (Something similar would happen for any prime-number root.)

Comment: "This isn't yielding the same answer" Meaning, when using some kind of program? Which one?

Comment: Related (actually, probably duplicate): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/415807/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of "raising to the power $1/n$" is not well defined in the complex numbers: generally there are $n$ candidates for what "$z^{1/n}\,$" might mean. The five possible values of the left-hand side of your equation are just the same as the five possible values of the right-hand side, namely the five complex roots of $z^5=1$. In the real numbers, it is possible to assign a unique real value to $x^{1/5}$, and the notation is therefore not problematic for real $x$.

Comment: What I'm doing is I'm equating two complex numbers, but when I raise them to 1/n, the complex numbers aren't turning out to be the same anymore The equation in my question was just an example. Am I missing some law regarding raising complex numbers in polar form to some power? Do the laws of indices still work?

Comment: @Dieblitzen: I hope that my expanded explanation makes this clear now.

Comment: Oh right I realise it now. The 5 values are equal, I just compared the immediate answer using De Moivre's. Thanks